# Compute matrix inverse using biogo?

Tags: matrix, go, matrix-inverse, kalman-filter

I'm working on a Kalman filter implementation in Go. After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536029/go-matrix-library) thread, I decided to use biogo for matrix operations. However, it appears from [the documentation](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/biogo.matrix) that biogo doesn't provide a function to calculate the inverse of a matrix.

Does anyone know otherwise or know of an easy way to calculate the inverse using the functions that biogo does provide? Thanks!

Comment: Is your implementation open source? I am considering starting such a KF library in go as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to switch to the [github.com/gonum/matrix](https://github.com/gonum/matrix) package, then it provides an [Inverse](http://godoc.org/github.com/gonum/matrix/mat64#Inverse) function that you can use. The interfaces of the two packages appear similar.

From posts on the [gonum-dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gonum-dev) mailing list, it appears that gonum/matrix is the way forward (and will eventually replace biogo.matrix).

Comment: Gonum/matrix is primarily written by Dan Kortschak who also writes biogo, in fact, I'm pretty sure that gonum/matrix started as more or less a fork of biogo.matrix. You're right that the endgame is for gonum/matrix to replace it.

Comment: Dan suggested using gonum/matrix when I asked him on the biogo mailing list as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should check if you really need the inverse matrix or if everything you do with it is solving some linear system.

For instance, if your formula is x=AB^(-1)Cy, then you decompose it into the steps w=Cy, z=solve(B,w), x=Az, completely avoiding the inverse matrix. So if your application is vector in - vector out, chances are that the inverse is not needed.

Comment: this helped implement pseudo inverse using gonum. The linear regression solution w = (X'X)^(-1) X'y can be implemented using gonum as w.Solve(X'X, X'y). where X' is X transposed.

Comment: As you have the Lapack functions available, it is numerically more stable to compute the QR decomposition of $X$ and then solve Rw=Q'y, w=solve(R, Q'y) with the reduced dimensions of R. Purists use the SVD of X to cover all possible cases.